# Trying to return a value from a function in a switch statement -JS-

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm trying to make switch statements that can answer some questions that I add it to it . 
I want the answers end with the user's name , so if you typed in the prompt "My name is Alex" it will save Alex in the "var username ;" 
I want the "username" has the value even before defined the "sendUserName" function.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var ask = prompt("Ask me anything >>").toLowerCase();

            function write(x) {
                document.write(x)
            };
            //Capitalize the first letter func :
            function capitalize(string) {
                return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
            }
            //..............
            var question = ask.split(" ");
            var date = new Date;
            var userName;
            //...............................
            write(userName); // <------ here the issue , undefined !
            if (question[0] === "what") {
                switch (question[1]) {
                    case "time":
                        switch (question[2]) {
                            case "is":
                                switch (question[3]) {
                                    case "it":
                                        write(date);
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                };
                                break;
                            default:
                        };
                        break;
                    case "is":
                        switch (question[2]) {
                            case "your":
                                switch (question[3]) {
                                    case "name":
                                        write("Alex !");
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                };
                                break;
                            default:
                        };
                        break;
                    default:
                        write("unknown");
                };
            } else if (question[0] === "my") {
                switch (question[1]) {
                    case "name":
                        switch (question[2]) {
                            case "is":
                                userName = capitalize(question[3]);;
                                alert("Your name is saved, " + userName);

                                function sendUserName() {
                                    return userName;
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                        };
                        break;
                    default:
                };
            };
            sendUserName();
            write(userName); // <------- it's work here
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. Can you provide expected input/output examples and specify what is not working?

Comment: Sure ,
I'm trying to print the value in the variable "userName" .. that's the main goal ...
I made switch statement that if the user typed in the prompt window 
"my name is anyName"  it goes to the second if statement (question[0] ==my) question[0] in this case =my .So it will go to the switch statement and to the next switch statement till it be in the case "is" with the function sendUserName... What is not working is the "write(username);" in the first of the code . @hallucinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the first `write(userName)` is called before you'd go through the if-else statements and the switches. A workaround (which would also improve the structure in my opinion) is to define a new function `processor(input)` and put all the logic there, then call that function with user input as the parameter before calling `write()`. See code below:

```
var ask = prompt("Ask me anything >>").toLowerCase();

function write(x) { document.write(x) };
//Capitalize the first letter func :
function capitalize(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
//..............

var input = ask.split(" ");
var date = new Date;
var userName;
//...............................
processor(question); // the processor function is called with the value of variable question

write(userName); // <------ Now it is defined even here

function processor(input) {
  if (input[0] === "what") {

  switch (input[1]) {
    case "time":
      switch (input[2]) {
        case "is":
          switch (input[3]) {
            case "it":
              write(date);
              break;
            default:
          };
          break;
        default:
      };
      break;
    case "is":
      switch (input[2]) {
        case "your":
          switch (input[3]) {
            case "name":
              write("Alex !");
              break;
            default:
          };
          break;
        default:

      };
      break;

    default:
      write("unknown");

  };

} else if (input[0] === "my") {

  switch (input[1]) {
    case "name":
      switch (input[2]) {
        case "is":

          userName = capitalize(input[3]);;
          alert("Your name is saved, " + userName);
          break;

        default:
      };
      break;



    default:
  };
};
}

function sendUserName() {
  return userName;
}

sendUserName();
```

I haven't touched your code much. I just dumped all your logic inside function `processor(input)` and also took function `sendUserName()` out of it, making it global. You could, of course, put it back if you want, but then be aware that if you don't reach the part of the logic where that function is defined, you might hit an error by calling the function.

Comment: Could you please tell me why we defined the processer function ? and what the "input" parameter did ? @AryKay

Comment: Check my updated answer. We defined `processor(input)` so we could isolate the logic from the global scope. In general it is a good idea to define functions for as much logic as we can. The input parameter is a local parameter, whose value you can define. Note that in line 14 `processor(question);` is called, meaning the value of `input` within the processor function is identical to the value of the variable `question`. You could read about synchronous and asynchronous functions in Javascript to get a better idea of the order in which code is executed.